# How to limit outbound rule scope to a specific site using url rewrite on IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I am using url rewrite on a IIS to act as an reverse-proxy.

One of the http services behind the proxy is a portal. The html returned by the portal as many resources that are referenced using a relative path, like /images/logo.png

Because the portal is accessed from outside as mydomain.com/portalX i need to create a outbound rule that rewrite any relative references inside the html to add the suffix portalX, so path :

```
/images/logo.png
```

will become

```
/portalX/images/logo.png
```

Problem is that i need to set a precondition that restricts the outbound rule to a specific site. If i dont', url rewrite rewrites all relative paths for all protected sites.

How do i do that? There is any other way to do this?

Here is the rule i need to restrict appliance to PortalX:

```
<rule name="PortalX - Relative paths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" value="/PortalX/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<preConditions>
    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />          
     </preCondition>
</preConditions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a way [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing), by adding the following condition to the rule:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(portalX)/.*" />
```

Note: portalX is the name of the domain behind the proxy.

Here the complete rule definition:

```
<rule name="PortalX - Relative paths" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(portalX)/.*" />
     </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" value="/PortalX/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```